# Почему .NET IDE обнаруживает файл .resx, но не отображает в нем описанные ошибки?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

создал новые resx для новых языков описал там код ошибки и почему то он не доступен хотя все пути до самого resx правильный В чем возможно ошибся что он не видит ошибку? 0-O

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]